# C++ - How to create new instance of a multimap using new operator?

Tags: c++, multimap

I am trying something like this -

```
//creation of multimap
multimap <int, string> prioritized_list;
//declared pointer for multimap
multimap <int, string>::const_pointer plist_pointer;
//tried to create instance of multimap.
plist_pointer=new prioritized_list;
```

I have to create new instance of multimap in a function, that needs to be called multiple times.

I am new to C++. Please let me know if I am considering anything wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely don't want to use `new`. Unlike in languages like Java, the `new` keyword is *not* needed for every object creation in C++, and unlike in many other languages, objects created with `new` are **not automatically destroyed** when you no longer need them. You instead have to delete them manually with `delete`.

Also, `new` does not return the newly created object itself but a pointer to it, allowing you to do nasty things like storing the pointer, later deleting the object and then accidentally attempting to access it through the stored pointer, which may crash the program.

All of this creates endless problems and bugs. Especially if you are a newbie (or if you gain more experience and *think* you can finally handle the complexity :)).

In C++, normal object creation doesn't require `new`. It is much simpler. Your first line *is* already object creation:

```
multimap <int, string> prioritized_list;
```

No need for `new` here.